# WPF App trouble adding new record

Tags: entity-framework, wpf-controls, binding

I know that I'm missing something.

Right now I am creating a very simple WPF app and I am simply trying to add a new record through a Window with many textboxes and Datepickers on a Grid. Through debugging I can tell that the record is being added, but the UI does not change/update, sticking on the same record, giving me no opportunity to populate the rew records' fields. What results is that it cannot save because I have a field that is not nullable. I am thinking I need to update the claimInventoryViewSource which is the DataContext of the main grid, but I have no idea how to do that.

Here is my code right now:

```
//Create a new claim
   var newClaim = new Claim();
   newClaim.DateCreated = DateTime.Today;
   _context.AddToClaims(newClaim);
   _claims.Add(newClaim);
```

This seems to work, but what am I missing is the line to have the UI update to the new record?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out! I added these lines of code and had to tweak some things in the XAML, but I got it to work.

```
private CollectionViewSource _claimViewSource;
...

_context.Claims.AddObject(new Claim());
_claimViewSource.View.Refresh();
_claimViewSource.View.MoveCurrentToLast();
```

Thank you for your assistance!